# How to troubleshoot kubectl connectivity issue on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

We have a couple of K8S clusters on GKE. Suddenly the production cluster is not avialable to us via `kubectl` (meaning it fails with timeout error).
I checked the K8S API of the cluster and everything seems to be working and I can work with the cluster from within the cloud shell (via the same IP of the master node).
I also scanned 443 port from my local machine and it says `filtered`. But I'm not sure what exactly is the root cause.
I also checked firewall rules and there's no `deny` blocking this.
What else do I need to check?

**Update 1**
I ran `tcptraceroute` for two clusters endpoints. The one which is responding to `kubectl` commands, made it through to the destination after 20 hops. But the result for the above mentioned cluster is failed:

```
❯ sudo tcptraceroute <Master Node IP> 443
Selected device en0, address 192.168.1.238, port 50617 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to <Master Node IP> on TCP port 443 (https), 30 hops max
 1  192.168.1.1  3.527 ms  2.436 ms  2.578 ms
 2  some ip  17.407 ms  17.644 ms  18.379 ms
 3  some ip  17.172 ms  17.487 ms  17.676 ms
 4  some ip  17.173 ms  17.258 ms  17.292 ms
 5  some ip  30.990 ms  30.630 ms  30.745 ms
 6  108.170.241.236  31.337 ms  31.384 ms  32.783 ms
 7  209.85.254.49  31.290 ms  31.320 ms  278.574 ms
 8  142.250.227.193  35.582 ms  39.082 ms  84.725 ms
 9  209.85.142.95  41.474 ms * 614.860 ms
10  108.170.231.173  38.148 ms  36.335 ms  35.805 ms
11  * * * # this should be 72.14.234.27
...
20  * * * # this must have ended here at <some ip>.bc.googleusercontent.com
...
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

Comment: are there any upgrades happening ? The control plane becomes unavailable certain times.

Comment: I don't think so. The notification has been showing "Node upgrade available" for some time. Also, as I said, the CP is avaialble from within the cloud shell. It's just the connection from my local machine that is blocked. There's some other connectivity issues going on in the cluster (failing liveness of some pods, but not all) :confused:

Answer (score 0):

So there's this feature called `Master Authorized Networks` which, if enabled, blocks connections from non-authorized networks.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a node directly using SSH and use [toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox).

Install ping library with the command **apt-get install iputils-ping** and install traceroute library with the command **apt-get install traceroute** in order to verify the connectivity from the node to your IP of on-prem.

Also, you can connect in to a specific pod with the command **kubectl exec -it pod-name -- /bin/bash** and install the same libraries for the node in order to run connectivity tests.

On the other hand, there are three configuration combinations to control access to the cluster endpoints, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#endpoints), and choose the best meet your needs.